# How to prove that the set of all probability distributions is convex set?

Tags: convex-analysis

Suppose we have a set $X=\{1,...,n\}$ where $n$ is a natural number.

Let $\Delta(X)$ be the set of all probability distributions over $X$.

Then $\Delta(X)$ is a convex set.

How do we interpret convexity in this case? What would be sufficient to show to prove that $\Delta(X)$ is a convex set?

I know that the elements of $\Delta(X)$ satisfy two properties, namely: non-negativity and the sum of all the elements is equal to $1$. But I am unsure how to start proving convexity.

Comment: You can define $$\Delta(X) = \left\{(p_1, ..., p_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sum_{i=1}^n p_i=1, p_i \geq 0 \: \forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}\right\}$$ So $\Delta(X) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Then use the definition of a convex set. Do you know the definition?

Comment: @Michael I am not familiar with the definition of a convex set and although I have searched in the internet, I am not sure which one is appropriate. Could you please direct me to a good source?

Comment: Def: A set $\mathcal{A}$ is a _convex set_ if for all $\vec{x},\vec{y} \in \mathcal{A}$ and all $\theta \in [0,1]$ we have $$\theta \vec{x} + (1-\theta) \vec{y} \in \mathcal{A}$$